# Divide a List to two Lists based on even/odd index

Tags: scala

I have to divide a list to two list based on their index. I did this:

```
def divide2[A](l: List[A]) = {
  l.zipWithIndex.partition(x => x._2 % 2 == 0)
}
println(divide2(List(1, 3, 5, 6, 7)))
```

It gives `(List((1,0), (5,2), (7,4)),List((3,1), (6,3)))` but the output i want should be: `(List(1, 5, 7),List(3, 6))`. The question is how to take only the first element? I tried with `.map(x => x._1)` but this doesnt work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?" Do you get a compilation error?

Comment: Partition will give you a `Tuple2` whose first element will have even indices and whose second element will have odd indices. You'll have to deconstruct that tuple and map each of those separately.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 2):

After `.partition` you got *two* lists in a tuple, so you have to map twice:

```
   val (even, odd) = l.zipWithIndex.partition(_._2 % 2 == 0)
   (even.map(_._1), odd.map(_._2))
```

Comment: so is there any simpler option to do with builtin whitout partition?

Comment: Not that I know of ... depends on your definition of "simple" I guess ... Personally, to me, this seems simple enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Without `partition()` and without `zip()`. (Not that there's anything *wrong* with either.)

```
def divide2[A](l: List[A]): (List[A],List[A]) = l match {
  case a::b::rest => val (ra, rb) = divide2(rest)
                     (a::ra, b::rb)
  case a::Nil     => (a::Nil, Nil)
  case _          => (Nil, Nil)
}

divide2(List(1, 3, 5, 6, 7))
//res0: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 5, 7),List(3, 6))
```

Simple? Depends on your definition of "simple."